# How can I underline whitespaces in VS Code using textMateRules?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code and would like to have markdown headings displayed underlined in the source code. I have added the following configuration:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": [
                "markup.heading.markdown",
            ],
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#C0C3CA",
                "fontStyle": "underline",
            }
        },
    ],
}
```

This basically works. The spaces in between the words however are not underlined, see this screenshot:

[image]

Is there a possibility to have these underlined as well?

According to the scope inspector the spaces also have the `markup.heading.markdown` scope, just like the words. So I don't see why they do not get underlined.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It conflicts with `"editor.renderWhitespace": "all"` setting.

You can find out more a about why it happens on GitHub:

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/49462
- https://github.com/eclipse/che-che4z-lsp-for-hlasm/issues/6